# How can I make my search engine more efficient in Spark Java

Tags: java, apache-spark

## Context

Hello Everyone, I'm starting to learn Spark and currently doing a practice task that requires me to build a mini search engine program in Spark.

I am given a list of documents and queries and I'm expected to return a ranking for every query consisting of the relevant documents that have been scored by a function given.

I will need to do pre-processing by doing stopword removal, stemming, and tokenization for the documents (queries have been pre-processed), then I will need to remove duplicates based on title similarity

## Utilities

The utilities and objects I'm given are included below

### Functions

1. `public static double getDPHScore(short termFrequencyInCurrentDocument, int totalTermFrequencyInCorpus, int currentDocumentLength, double averageDocumentLengthInCorpus, long totalDocsInCorpus)` // used to calculate the score for a document, this will return a score for every query item, and the score for the document will be the average of the query scores
2. `public static double similarity(String textSnippet1, String textSnippet2)` // used to calculate similarity between the titles
3. `public List<String> process(String text)` // this is a processing function that does all the pre-processing (stemming, tokenization, etc.)

### Java Objects

1. `Query(String originalQuery, List<String> queryTerms, short[] queryTermCounts)`
2. `NewsArticle(String id, String article_url, String title, String author, long published_date, List<ContentItem> contents, String type, String source)`
3. `RankedResult(String docid, NewsArticle article, double score)`
4. `DocumentRanking(Query query, List<RankedResult> results)`

## Current Approach

This is the code template given:

```
public static List<DocumentRanking> rankDocuments(SparkSession spark, String queryFile, String newsFile) {
        // Load queries and news articles
        Dataset<Row> queriesjson = spark.read().text(queryFile);
        Dataset<Row> newsjson = spark.read().text(newsFile); // read in files as string rows, one row per article
        
        // Perform an initial conversion from Dataset<Row> to Query and NewsArticle Java objects
        Dataset<Query> queries = queriesjson.map(new QueryFormaterMap(), Encoders.bean(Query.class)); // this converts each row into a Query
        Dataset<NewsArticle> news = newsjson.map(new NewsFormaterMap(), Encoders.bean(NewsArticle.class)); // this converts each row into a NewsArticle
```

### Stage 1 (a map operation)

My idea to get the statistics needed for the DPH scoring, from each document, is to map each `NewsArticle` to a new object called NewsStats which has the following signature `NewsArticleStats(String document_id, int document_length, String title, Map<String, Integer> index)`. The `index` field contains the unique words (keys) in the document and their frequency (values)

During this mapping I have 2 accumulators that will count the total word frequency `LongAccumulator word_freq` and number of documents in corpus `LongAccumulator doc_count`

### Stage 2 (reduce operation)

At this stage I have 4 out of the 5 fields needed for DPH:

- `termFrequencyInCurrentDocument` exists in each `NewsStats.index` object
- `int currentDocumentLength`, exists in each `NewsStats.document_length` object
- `double averageDocumentLengthInCorpus` can be calculated through the accumulators `word_freq / doc_count`
- `long totalDocsInCorpus` can be accessed through the accumulator `doc_count`

The only missing thing is `totalTermFrequencyInCorpus`, and to get that I thought of merging all the Hashmaps from the `NewsStats` objects into a single Hashmap and then broadcast that Hashmap to be used during query evaluation.

The merging is happening in a reduce operation that looks like this:

```
public NewsArticleWordMap call(NewsArticleWordMap val1, NewsArticleWordMap val2) throws Exception {
        // Merged map
        Map<String,Integer> v1 = val1.getIndex();
        Map<String,Integer> v2 = val2.getIndex();
        
        Map<String, Integer> mergedMap = new HashMap<>(v1);

        // Iterate over map2 and merge
        v2.forEach((key, value) -> mergedMap.merge(key, value, Integer::sum));
        return new NewsArticleWordMap(mergedMap);
    }
```

Just to note: `NewsArticleWordMap` is just the result of another Map operation to get only the word Hashmap from `NewsStats` objects

## Problem

This takes forever to execute, the task indicates that the dataset, consisting of 509K documents and 83 million words (660K unique words), should finish all the processing in around 5-7 minutes (adjusted for my hardware), but it took almost 30 minutes just to finish the reduce step which combines all the hashmaps, I still haven't even ranked any documents, So I would like some guidance on what a more efficient architecture could look like and what I'm doing incorrectly. I will include the main topology code below if anyone finds it useful

## Current Topology

```
        LongAccumulator document_count_acc = spark.sparkContext().longAccumulator();
        LongAccumulator word_freq_acc = spark.sparkContext().longAccumulator();
        
        NewsArticleToNewsArticleStatsMap statsMapFunction = new NewsArticleToNewsArticleStatsMap(document_count_acc, word_freq_acc);
        Dataset<NewsArticleStats> newsArticleStats = news.map(statsMapFunction, Encoders.bean(NewsArticleStats.class));
        
        newsArticleStats.count();
        long document_count = document_count_acc.value();
        long word_freq = word_freq_acc.value();
        double avg_document_length = (1.0 * word_freq) / document_count;
    
        Dataset<NewsArticleWordMap> documentMaps = newsArticleStats.map(new NewsArticleStatsToHashmap(), Encoders.bean(NewsArticleWordMap.class));
        NewsArticleWordMap fullWordMap = documentMaps.reduce(new HashmapMergeReducer());
        
        Broadcast<Map<String, Integer>> broadcastedWordMap = JavaSparkContext.fromSparkContext(spark.sparkContext()).broadcast(fullWordMap.getIndex());

// The ranking should take place next
```